# Cannot convert expression to type "Xamarin.Forms.Application" Xamarin Android App

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

My Xamarin.Forms app used to work, but for some reason it just stopped working. This is the error I get:

> Argument #1 cannot convert 'BadgerBand.Droid.App' expression to type 'Xamarin.Forms.Application' (CS1503)

I am also getting a CS1502 error, which is:

> The best overloaded method match for `Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity.LoadApplication(Xamarin.Forms.Application)' has some invalid arguments (CS1502) (BadgerBand.Droid)

Does anyone know how I can fix this?

```
using System;
using BadgerBand;
using Android.App;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Content.PM;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Views;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;

namespace BadgerBand.Droid
{
[Activity (Label = "BadgerBand.Droid", Icon = "@drawable/icon", MainLauncher = true, ConfigurationChanges = ConfigChanges.ScreenSize | ConfigChanges.Orientation)]
public class MainActivity : global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsApplicationActivity
{
    protected override void OnCreate (Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate (bundle);
        //BadgerBand.Init(typeof(BadgerBand).Assembly);
        global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init (this, bundle);
        //LoadApplication (new Xamarin.Forms.Application ());
        LoadApplication (new App ());
    }
}
}
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with Xamarin code.. but does your App class not inherit from Xamarin.Forms.Application?

Comment: if you are using a PCL, App should be a class in your PCL project that inherits from Application.  You also need to be sure that your Droid project has a reference to the PCL project.

Comment: I have a class named App so i'm confused why it isn't working..?

Comment: is it in the right project?  Does it inherit from the correct base class?

Comment: I fixed up your prose and made the error messages easier to read.  Also, txt-speak and fluff like "I am confused :(" is discouraged.